# Shopify Python API Delete a customer metafield

Tags: python, shopify

Is there a way to use the Shopify Python API to DELETE a metafield by ID or value?

Couldn't find a thing in the [documentation](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_python_api)

This is what I tried:

`shopify.Metafield.delete(key=data['id'])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the method I just found out, I cycle through the entire product catalog (I think it could work with other resources too), then through each metafield until I find the metafield I want. Then I call metafield.destroy(). Like this:

```
for product in products:
    for metafield in product.metafields():
        if metafield.namespace == "global":
            metafield.destroy()
```

Originally I was working to do `product.delete(metafield)` but I kept getting a 406 error that I'm not sure how to resolve yet.

Note that I am fine destroying my metafields this way because each metafield I use (to this point) is a unique product identifier, and not shared by any other resource and so destroying the entire metafield would have no negative consequences. I am not aware if this method destroys the metafield entirely, but would test the following case before using on shared metafields:

```
Assume product A has metafield X
Assume product B has metafield X
destroy metafield X from product A
does product B still have metafield X?
```

Perhaps you can adapt this solution to something that works for your needs.

EDIT: Shopify's python online documentation is horrid. I used dir() and help() to find all of this.

Comment: I can't believe how dire the documentation is. Thanks for your help. I got it working. 